# close current dialogbox and return to previous dialog box android

Tags: java, android, dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(Questionnaire.this);
builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.seal_catanauan);
builderSingle.setTitle("Select survey to use: ");

final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        Questionnaire.this,
        android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
//                        arrayAdapter.add("Hardik");
//                        arrayAdapter.add("Archit");
//                        arrayAdapter.add("Jignesh");
//                        arrayAdapter.add("Umang");
//                        arrayAdapter.add("Gatti");
System.out.println(jsonArray.length());
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    // Get JSON object
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
    arrayAdapter.add("(" + obj.get("sysid").toString() + ")" + obj.get("surveytitle").toString());
    // DB QueryValues Object to insert into SQLite
    //controller.insertusername(obj.get("username").toString(),obj.get("password").toString(),obj.get("fname").toString(),obj.get("mname").toString(),obj.get("lname").toString(),obj.get("suffix").toString(),obj.get("status").toString());
}
builderSingle.setCancelable(false);
builderSingle.setNegativeButton(
        "Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent todashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
                startActivity(todashboard);
                finish();
            }
        });

builderSingle.setAdapter(
        arrayAdapter,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Questionnaire.this);
                String surveyid = strName.split("[\\(\\)]")[1];
                builderInner.setMessage(strName.split("[\\(\\)]")[2]);
                builderInner.setTitle("Your Selected Survey is");
                builderInner.setCancelable(false);
                builderInner.setPositiveButton(
                        "Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(
                                    DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builderInner.setNegativeButton(
                        "Back",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
//                              Questionnaire.super.onBackPressed();
                            }
                        });
                builderInner.show();
            }
        });
builderSingle.show();
```

> I tried using `dialog.dismiss();` this closes both dialog box.

**How to close only one dialog box and return to previous dialog box?**

I want to close the current dialog box which is `builderInner` when i click on the Back button and i want to return to previous dialog box which is `builderSingle`.

> I tried using `dialog.dismiss();` this closes both dialog box.

**How to close only one dialog box and return to previous dialog box?**

Comment: why you have tagged jquery?

Comment: sorry i just wrong click i will remove. it is suppose to be java for android

Answer (score 0):

i change my builderSingle to:

`final AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(Questionnaire.this);`

It is now **final** and then in my

```
builderInner.setNegativeButton(
             "Back",
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(
              DialogInterface dialog,
              int which) {
              builderSingle.show();//added this line
              //Questionnaire.super.onBackPressed();
   }
});
```

I added **builderSingle.show();** this line inside back button click.

I am just worried than after setting builderSingle to final i may cause some abnormalities I am not aware.

Feel free to update the answer to make it correct.As of now it is working as expected